# Apache Cordova (3.4.0) CLI install on Windows

Tags: apache, cordova, npm

I am trying to install cordova, I do excatly what is said in the [CLI tutorial here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface).
After creating a new App

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

I list all platforms and see following:
[image]
Where is other platforms liks ios? Moreover, when I try

```
cordova platform add android
```

I get following error:
[image]

What I am doing wrong or what is wrong with the Cordova?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work, this cordova command needs to use some programs located into your `sdk/tools` directory. You need also have installed **apache ant**.

Then you must add these directories into your `PATH` system variable:

**Background:**

- let's assume you have installed your [Android SDK](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.2.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide_requirements_and_support) to the `c:\sdk\android` directory
- you have installed you **Apache ant** to the `c:\tools\apache-ant` directory

Then you must create two system variables:

1. `ANDROID_HOME` with the `c:\sdk\android` value
2. `ANT_HOME` with the `c:\tools\apache-ant` value

Finally, you must modify the `PATH` variable and add those two to the end of the `PATH`' value:

```
;%PATH%\tools;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

**NOTE:** for those who uses Linux, the instruction differs a bit.

More documentation available [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide).

Comment: Ok, but what about iOS? Where it is not in available platforms list?

Comment: For cordova, you need a mac to build for iOS and an apple developer account. That's why it isn't listed on a Windows computer. However, you can use phonegap build to build an iOS application in the cloud without a mac, but you are still going to need an apple developer account.